# Css and js graph

Tags: javascript, css

I have a graph made out of divs ( basically connected lines going up and down ), which indicates if current temperature goes up or down. I have an array of temperatures and based on them I do this:

```
let denivelationPerStep = 17;
let bottomPadding = 20;
// calc of prevTemp and angle
let shift = prevTemp * denivelationPerStep + bottomPadding;
dom.style.bottom = shift + 'px';
dom.style.transform = 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)';
```

Before I do this calculation, all the divs are just horizontal lines that basically form one straight line. I adjust each next div to push it up or down and rotate it accordingly.
 It works just fine for certain temperatures ( say between 5 and 20 degrees ). After that, the divs that form the graph just start going too far ( out of their parent divs ). My question is, how to normalize the bottom shift and rotation, so that even if temperature is, say, -20 degrees, the div will not go too far, but will remain in its parent div. I think the solution may be to adjust bottomPadding and denivelationPerStep based on the maximum and minimum temperatures in my array. Is that correct? What would be a good solution ( formula )? Thanks.

Two examples are:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSwgB.jpg and 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBqTL.jpg. In one of the pictures, the graph totally disappears.

Comment: Please include a minimal verifiable working example that demonstrates the issue at hand.

Comment: One second. I wll upload pictures

Comment: @PeterUlev Pictures are pretty useless. Post code that works. Use the code snippet button (CTRL + M) to put in a working code sample that demonstrates your issue as minimal as possible

Comment: I understand. The problem is that the code is dependent on other components and libraries ( as handlebars ), variables called from and API in different classes, and it is hard to paste all the code here. It would not work.

Comment: right click, inspect element on your rendered code. Copy all relevant CSS and html code, recreate the end result here, then recreate the code that simulates the same behaviour on a press of a button.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not allowed to do that. I can delete the post if it is not appropriate. Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to help without code reproducing the issue at hand. And seriously, it's a simple weather graph with multiple columns, not something really unique to the internet. Reproduce something similar that shows the same issue, that is not the "proprietary code" We only need something that shows the same behaviour that you wish to fix

Comment: Okay, I will do it tonight when I get home. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I fixed the problem. I had to define a mapping function to map temperatures outside of the interval [4, 10], to that interval. That was all. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: @PeterUlev Often when narrowing a problem down to be able to post here, you find hte solution in that process. Good job!

Comment: Yes, that happens often to me! Thanks, man ! Have a good day.